# How to use IList for generating databases?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a "database" generated from a random list of locations, which attaches a random continent and a random category to each one.

I wanted to change the RandomItem to NextItem so it just selects the next item of the list of locations rather than randomly selecting them, unfortunately I don't know enough to know what to search for to solve this problem.

I was hoping I could use the value of (i) when it generates the next place but that didn't seem to work.

How would I go about changing the NextItem to do this?

```
    public class TestPlacesRepository : PlacesRepository
    {

        const int placeCount = 10;
        readonly List<Location> locations;
        readonly List<Continent> continents;
        readonly List<Category> categories;
        readonly Random random;

        public TestPlacesRepository() : base()
        {
            //Generates the seed for the rng
            this.random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
            this.locations = new List<Location>();
            this.continents = new List<Continent>();
            this.categories = new List<Category>();

            GenerateLocations();
            GenerateContinents();
            GenerateCategories();

            for (int i = 0; i < placeCount; i++)
                Places.Add(GeneratePlace(i));

        }

        Place GeneratePlace(int number)
        {
            //Creates the x "random" locations from the list of locations below
            Place place = new Place(
                NextItem<Location>(locations),
                RandomItem<Continent>(continents),
                RandomItem<Category>(categories),
                number % 3 == 0);
            return place;
        }

        T NextItem<T>(IList<T> list)
        {
            int index = (int)(i * (list.Count));
            return list[index];
        }

        T RandomItem<T>(IList<T> list)
        {
            int index = (int)(random.NextDouble() * 0.99 * (list.Count));
            return list[index];
        }

        void GenerateLocations()
        {
            //1st 10 places
            locations.Add(new Location("Temples of Angkor", "Cambodia"));
            locations.Add(new Location("Great Barrier Reef", "Australia"));
            locations.Add(new Location("Machu Picchu", "Peru"));
            locations.Add(new Location("Great Wall of China", "China"));
            locations.Add(new Location("Taj Mahal", "India"));
            locations.Add(new Location("Arizona - Grand Canyon National Park", "USA"));
            locations.Add(new Location("Colosseum", "Italy"));
            locations.Add(new Location("Iguazu Falls", "Brazil/Argentina"));
            locations.Add(new Location("Alhambra", "Spain"));
            locations.Add(new Location("Aya Sofya", "Turkey"));
         }
        void GenerateContinents()
        {
            //All 7 Continents
            continents.Add(new Continent("Africa"));
            continents.Add(new Continent("Antartica"));
            continents.Add(new Continent("Asia"));
            continents.Add(new Continent("Europe"));
            continents.Add(new Continent("North America"));
            continents.Add(new Continent("Oceania"));
            continents.Add(new Continent("South America"));
        }
        void GenerateCategories()
        {
            //All 7 Categories
            categories.Add(new Category("Activity/Modern Attraction"));
            categories.Add(new Category("District/Square/Town"));
            categories.Add(new Category("Historical Site"));
            categories.Add(new Category("Museum"));
            categories.Add(new Category("Nature/Landscape"));
            categories.Add(new Category("Palace/Castle/Fort/Ruin"));
            categories.Add(new Category("Religion"));
        }
```

type here

Comment: just maintain an index counter for each list

Comment: What @Jason says, or just shuffle the lists and start from the first item.

Comment: how would I go about making an index counter in this instance? I'm used to Matlab and the way I'd usually do it doesn't seem to work here

Comment: Shuffle the lists using a shuffle algorithm then place them in a queue

Comment: You need list to keep the index. But if you want to keep your generic method you will have to make some change. We can bind a Collection with the current index a new customemade collection that herite from `Collection<T>`, but add and public index.  And you can filter your generik method with `where T : ISomething<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use an index counter for each list

```
int nextLoc = 0;

Location NextLocation()
{
  var loc = locations[nextLoc];
  nextLoc++;
  return loc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option that would also work with any `IEnumerable` (which includes `IList`) would be to get the enumerator and then simply call `MoveNext` and return `Current` for each iteration, e.g.

```
IEnumerator<T> enumerator = null;

T NextItem<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    if (enumerator == null)
    {
        enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        return null;
    }

    return enumerator.Current;
}
```

Note, you should also explicitly call enumerator.Dispose after you've finished using it (it implements IDisposible). E.g. drop something like the following at the end of your constructor:

```
if (enumerator != null)
{
    enumerator.Dispose();
}
```

On recent C# versions this can be simplified to:

```
enumerator?.Dispose();
```

There's an obvious caveat that it will only work for the first collection it is used with (as the collection parameter is only used to initialise the enumerator on first use).